# Thread execution after .start() method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

I am wondering what happens in the following scenario:

Two threads are created:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread();
Thread t2 = new Thread();
```

Assume these just print out a string, the threads then call the .start() method:

```
t1.start();
t2.start():
```

My question is why do these threads print in a seemingly random order each time? I know threads execute concurrently but would `t1` not always finish before `t2` due to the sequential execution of the main process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling [start()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) on a `Thread` doesn't necessarily result in the thread running *immediately* after. It is possible for other things to happen in between your calling `start()` and the first line of your thread's `run()` method actually being run. And even once your `run()` is actually running, it's also possible that other things happen before, during, or after your `run()` method finishes.

In your question, you said: *"assume these just print out a string"* – here's an implementation of `run()` which does that:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println("my name is: " + getName());
}
```

So it's possible that `t1` *starts* to run first, but before it actually calls `System.out.println`, `t2` is allowed to execute and runs to completion, then `t1` is resumed.

If this kind of behavior won't work for your use case, you'll need to add some kind of concurrency protection to coordinate how and when your threads run.

**UPDATE:**

To illustrate the unpredictable sequence of thread execution, run this code a few times and observe the output:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            new TestThread(k).start();
        }
    }
}

class TestThread extends Thread {
    private final int k;

    TestThread(int k) {
        this.k = k;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.print(k + " ");
    }
}
```

Here is the output from one of my local runs:

```
7 0 1 5 4 6 3 2 8 9
```

Comment: So there are other factors outside my code that affect the threads? Even if t1 is the only thread runnable at that point and nothing would stop it?

Comment: correct – there is no guarantee what order your threads will run in

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I appreciate it

Comment: I added another example that you can cut+paste to run locally. The _run sequence_ may be different from the _start sequence_ ("may be" because they also might end up being the same, but you won't know beforehand). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.start()` doesn't guarantee execution. It will just make the Thread state runnable and hand over to the Thread Scheduler. It is the Thread Scheduler which decides which thread to run when.

Comment: But would the thread scheduler not see that t1 is runnable and execute it first anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you need code to execute in a defined order on multiple threads, you need to add synchronization code between those threads.

Otherwise, the system is free to schedule execution in any order it sees fit.

Comment: But if t1 was to call start() before t2, would the scheduler not execute t1 first because that is the only thread that is runnable at that point in time?